# Minutes Count IN Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Program in Python in which I have to trigger a block of Code after 3 minutes get passed, This could be done by getting minutes count i.e 3 or seconds count i.e 180 (in this case) can anybody tell me how to get this count. I have searched but discussions are all about elapsed time etc.

Comment: is your python code supposed to do something during those 3 minutes or just wait?

Comment: I am doing image processing, it will keep doing its work (i.e face detection and other work) during those 3 mins.

Comment: @csmckelvey I am working on Raspberry Pi and I already have 2 threads running on it, I am with limited resources here. Would prefer to avoid thread here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. What about using elapsed time to measure time?

```
import time

a=time.time()
b=0
while(b<180):
    b=time.time()-a
    # add any other code you need to do
```

just an idea...

Comment: What is **b** here? did you attempt to run this before posting?

I have tried to run this code and this is what I get
_NameError: name 'b' is not defined_

Comment: you are right. You can add b=0, just before the while loop ( I will edit the post) thanks